# NHibernate OrderBy Projection on Child Objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-order-by, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I have 2 entities `OrganisationMember` and `User`

An `OrganisationMember` has a object Property called `User` of type `User`.

I'm trying to write an NHibernate Query which will do a case insensitive sory by the `User.Email` property... (users typing emails into the system in various cases).

I've seen that you can use a SQLFunction Projection to basically upper case everything at the DB and order by that. but I'm having trouble applying this to the child object. Here's what I have so far.

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<OrganisationMembership>();

query.RootCriteria.SetFetchMode("User", FetchMode.Eager);

var projection = Projections.SqlFunction("UPPER", NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("Email"));

query.OrderBy(projection).Asc();
```

It keeps telling me that it doesn't know what "Email" is in the projection. I've also tried changing the projection to

```
var projection = Projections.SqlFunction("UPPER", NHibernateUtil.String,  Projections.Property("User.Email"));
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to:

```
User user = null;

query.JoinAlias(p => p.User, () => user);
```

equivalent to

```
query.JoinAlias(p => p.User, () => user, JoinType.InnerJoin);
```

and then

```
projection = Projections.SqlFunction("UPPER", 
                                     NHibernateUtil.String,
                                     Projections.Property(() => user.Email));
```

In NHibernate you always have to explicitly make the `Joins`. There are no implicit joins.